# how to give spry menu bar a 3D look? Dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I want to give my spry menu bar a 3D look when you click on it. Kind of a push effect.
Is there a way to do that?

Thankyou

Comment: you could achieve that with CSS3 box-shadow that give ur images depth if you are using text text-shadow

Comment: How can i use that with the spry menu bar?

Comment: you need to code your CSS - have u have a CSS already? it d be useful if u can post your html

Comment: I found out how it works, thankyou